# Is Firewall required in North Florida 2005 single story home?

Tags: framing

**Is Firewall required?**
 Home inspector; Inspecting a single story 2005 home in Northern Florida.  Garage panel attic access. I noticed the lack of firewall separating the garage from living space. 
Note: Garage not insulated and attic cooler than outside temperature. 
Thermal imaging read several degrees cooler than outside. "Attic felt cool"

Is Firewall required? and how would AC be leaking into attic?

Comment: I won't post this as an answer because this would be state-specific, and I'm in Va. The initial major code change was 2003. Not sure if Fl took it then or not, but we did.

Comment: Leaking AC has to be physically investigated. Could one, or a combination of a hundred things. Joints, lack of insulated duct, diy duct, lack of insulation, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The only requirement for a firewall that I am aware of, between the garage and living space was a layer of 5/8" fire code sheetrock over the whole wall that separates the garage from the living space. If there is a living space above the garage, then the ceiling needed it too. Although I think the latter statement is state specific. I believe in WA state it is not needed on the ceiling, at least in a new home I was working on, but in Maryland it was required.

The door into the garage from the house needed to be rated to withstand a 20 minute fire exposure.

Answer (score 1):

### Face it: [ducts leak](https://buildingscience.com/documents/insights/bsi-074-duct-dynasty)

Unless you go to the work of mastic'ing the snot out of your ducts, they'll leak in the tens of % -- it doesn't matter whether they were put in by a DIYer or a pro, or whether they were left bare or smothered in insulation.

The common Florida habit of putting the air handler in the attic just makes the matter worse.

As to the fire separation? In general (straight 2015 IRC), a 20-min door and regular 1/2" drywall suffice, unless there's habitable space above (which requires the 5/8" type X stuff on the garage ceiling).